# Why is PPA package not taken into account?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I have added the offical Firefox-next PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

So I get the following config in */etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-firefox-next-xenial.list*

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu xenial main
```

But the package doesn't upgrade to the PPA version.

### Question

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Policy (before)

```
$ apt policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 48.0+linuxmint1+sarah
  Candidate: 48.0+linuxmint1+sarah
  Version table:
     49.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 48.0+linuxmint1+sarah 700
        700 http://mint-mirror.gwendallebihan.net/packages sarah/upstream amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/mirror/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ftp.u-picardie.fr/mirror/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

### APT policy

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/official-extra-repositories.pref
Package: *
Pin: origin build.linuxmint.com
Pin-Priority: 700
```

### Solution

Based on [How do I cherry pick packages from a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/a/170265/22343)
Add the following rule to `/etc/apt/preferences.d/official-extra-repositories.pref` in order to prioritize the PPA (highest `Pin-Priority` will be used):

```
Package: *firefox*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam-firefox-next
Pin-Priority: 800
```

Then update and upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Does this solution work?

Comment: @tomas yep, why?

Comment: Cause you wrote "so far", as if there were more to come.

Comment: @tomas I removed the statement, thanks for your feedback